# How to loop through rows in MySQL and insert data based on the values of the next rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

This is my existing table in MySQL

```
name  UUID  date_time             org_id
SK    null  2017-04-19 01:36:34    2
SK    null  2017-04-19 01:36:53    2
SK    null  2017-04-19 01:37:23    2
TK    null  2017-02-11 01:37:20    5
TK    null  2017-02-11 01:37:31    5
KK    null  2017-01-01 11:37:33    1
```

I want to update the table and insert one unique UUID instead of null based on whether the name is same and the timestamp is within 1 minutes of each other and org_id is same in SQL.

Desired Output:

```
name  UUID  date_time             org_id
SK    we23  2017-04-19 01:36:34    2
SK    we23  2017-04-19 01:36:53    2
SK    we23  2017-04-19 01:37:23    2
TK    rt56  2017-02-11 01:37:20    5
TK    rt56  2017-02-11 01:37:31    5
KK    yu77  2017-01-01 11:37:33    1
```

Please let me know how do I write a SQL script to do this using MySQL workbench..

Comment: Does your table include a unique ID column that identifies the rows?

Comment: Where does the UUID come from?

Comment: Yes.. I do have one auto increment ID column

Comment: The UUID will be generated by MySQL's UUID() function.. just that it should be unique on groups based on the conditions mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with MySQL, but is rather complicated, because it needs several subqueries.

```
SELECT
    name, date_time, org_id, uuid
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            `name`, `date_time`, `org_id`, 
            (SELECT 
                sum(step) 
             FROM
             (
                  SELECT
                      t1.`name`, t1.`date_time`, t1.`org_id`,
                      case when exists 
                        (SELECT 1
                         FROM t AS t2 
                         WHERE t2.`name` = t1.`name` 
                           AND timestampdiff(second, t1.date_time, t2.date_time) < 60
                           AND t2.date_time > t1.date_time
                           ) 
                      then 0
                      else 1
                      end AS step
                  FROM
                      t AS t1
             ) AS ttt
             WHERE
                ttt.name <= t.name AND ttt.date_time <= ttt.date_time
            ) AS group_number
        FROM
            t
    ) AS ttt2
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 AS group_number, UUID() AS `uuid`
        UNION
        SELECT 2 AS group_number, UUID() AS `uuid`
        UNION
        SELECT 3 AS group_number, UUID() AS `uuid`
        -- and as many as needed
    ) u ON u.group_number = ttt2.group_number
ORDER BY
    name, date_time ;
```

You'll get:

```
name | date_time           | org_id | uuid                                
:--- | :------------------ | -----: | :-----------------------------------
KK   | 2017-01-01 11:37:33 |      1 | 636c0fcf-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:36:34 |      2 | 636c107a-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:36:53 |      2 | 636c107a-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:37:23 |      2 | 636c107a-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
TK   | 2017-02-11 01:37:20 |      5 | 636c108d-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
TK   | 2017-02-11 01:37:31 |      5 | 636c108d-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
```

If you want to update, do a JOIN of your original table with that one, and UPDATE.

---

This is done in several steps... First, you need to order your data, and identify at which point you need to "change group" (I call that a `step`). This will give you an intermediate table (ttt):

```
CREATE TABLE ttt AS
SELECT
    t1.`name`, t1.`date_time`, t1.`org_id`,
    case when 
         exists 
         (SELECT 1
          FROM t AS t2 
          WHERE 
            t2.`name` = t1.`name` 
             AND timestampdiff(second, t1.date_time, t2.date_time) < 60
             AND t2.date_time > t1.date_time
            ) 
    then 0
    else 1
    end AS step
FROM
    t AS t1
ORDER BY
   `name`, `date_time`, `org_id` ;
```

Table ttt is:

```
name | date_time           | org_id | step
:--- | :------------------ | -----: | ---:
KK   | 2017-01-01 11:37:33 |      1 |    1
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:36:34 |      2 |    0
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:36:53 |      2 |    0
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:37:23 |      2 |    1
TK   | 2017-02-11 01:37:20 |      5 |    0
TK   | 2017-02-11 01:37:31 |      5 |    1
```

From that table, for each row, compute the `SUM(all preceding steps)`. This is done by mans of:

```
CREATE TABLE ttt2 AS
SELECT
    `name`, `date_time`, `org_id`, 
    (SELECT 
        sum(step) 
     FROM
        ttt
     WHERE
        ttt.name <= t.name AND ttt.date_time <= ttt.date_time
    ) AS group_number
FROM
    t
ORDER BY
    `name`, `date_time`, `org_id` ;
```

And you'll get a second intermediate table, which I called `tt2`

```
name | date_time           | org_id | group_number
:--- | :------------------ | -----: | -----------:
KK   | 2017-01-01 11:37:33 |      1 |            1
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:36:34 |      2 |            2
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:36:53 |      2 |            2
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:37:23 |      2 |            2
TK   | 2017-02-11 01:37:20 |      5 |            3
TK   | 2017-02-11 01:37:31 |      5 |            3
```

Now, you change the `group_number` to an UUID by joining to a table of (1, UID1), (2, UID2), etc. tuples:

```
SELECT
    name, date_time, org_id, uuid
FROM
    ttt2 
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 AS group_number, UUID() AS `uuid`
        UNION
        SELECT 2 AS group_number, UUID() AS `uuid`
        UNION
        SELECT 3 AS group_number, UUID() AS `uuid`
        UNION
        SELECT 4 AS group_number, UUID() AS `uuid`
        -- and as many as you might need
    ) u ON u.group_number = ttt2.group_number 
ORDER BY
    name, date_time ;
```

And you finally get what you want

```
name | date_time           | org_id | uuid                                
:--- | :------------------ | -----: | :-----------------------------------
KK   | 2017-01-01 11:37:33 |      1 | 636bd83f-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:36:34 |      2 | 636bd8b9-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:36:53 |      2 | 636bd8b9-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
SK   | 2017-04-19 01:37:23 |      2 | 636bd8b9-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
TK   | 2017-02-11 01:37:20 |      5 | 636bd8c8-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
TK   | 2017-02-11 01:37:31 |      5 | 636bd8c8-5d3f-11e7-8f8c-00163ebcde7e
```

By substituting `ttt2` and `ttt` by its definitions on the last SQL, you get what you want in one query... although a "monster one".

NOTE: This query will probably be terribly inefficient; and, if you're programming, you're probably better of by just looping through your sorted data and deciding when you need to generate a new UUID.

You can check everything on *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=b0191c4e4bee5da24af97f192f299d28)*

Comment: You're welcome Sharvil. If you think the question has been asnwered, it is more-or-less customary to mark it as *accepted*, so that people can concentrate on the extensive list of *already non-answered ones*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help..
I also figured out an approx solution to this question:
Here is my query:

```
update table as u, 
        (SELECT UUID() as UUID, name, org_id,date_time 
        FROM table 
        group by name, org_id, DATE_FORMAT(date_time, "%Y-%m-%e %H-%i")) as b
set u.UUID = b.UUID
where (u.name = b.name OR (u.name is null and u.name is null)) 
    and (u.org_id = b.org_id OR ( u.org_id is null and b.org_id is null)) 
    and DATE_FORMAT(u.date_time, "%Y-%m-%e %H-%i") = DATE_FORMAT(b.date_time, "%Y-%m-%e %H-%i");
```